# Java sending byte[] through sockets...wrong length read

Tags: java, sockets

For my homework assignment, I have a network of Nodes that are passing messages to each other. Each Node is connected to a set amount of other Nodes (I'm using 4 for testing). Each Link has a weight, and all the Nodes have computed the shortest path for how they want their messages sent. Every Packet that is sent is composed of the message protocol (a hard-coded int), an integer that tells how many messages have passed through the sending Node, and the routing path for the Packet.

Every Node has a Thread for each of its Links. There is an active Socket in each Link. The Packets are sent by adding a 4-byte int to the beginning of the message telling the message's length.

Everything works fine until I stress the network. For my test, there are 10 Nodes, and I get 5 of them to send 10000 packets in a simple while() loop with no Thread.sleep(). Without exception, there is always an error at some point during execution at the if(a!=len) statement.

Please let me know if I can clarify anything. Thanks in advance! Here is the code (from the Link Thread; send() and forward() are called from the Node itself):

```
protected void listen(){
    byte[] b;
    int len;
    try{
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
        while(true){
            len = in.readInt();
            b = new byte[len];
            int a = in.read(b,0,len);
            if(a!=len){
System.out.println("ERROR: " + a + "!=" + len);
                throw new SocketException(); //may have to fix...this will happen when message is corrupt/incomplete
            }
            Message m = new Message(b);
            int p = m.getProtocol();
            switch (p){
                case CDNP.PACKET:
                    owner.incrementTracker();
                    System.out.print("\n# INCOMMING TRACKER: " + m.getTracker() + "\n>>> ");
                    owner.forward(m);
            }
        }
    }catch (IOException e){
e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void send(int tracker){
    String[] message = { Conv.is(CDNP.PACKET), Conv.is(tracker), owner.getMST().toString() };
    Message m = new Message(message);
    forward(m);
}

public synchronized void forward(Message m){
    try{
        OutputStream out = sock.getOutputStream();
        //convert length to byte array of length 4
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(4+m.getLength());
        bb.putInt(m.getLength());
        bb.put(m.getBytes());
        out.write(bb.array());
        out.flush();
    }catch (UnknownHostException e){
System.out.println("ERROR: Could not send to Router at " + sock.getRemoteSocketAddress().toString());
        return;
    }catch (IOException e1){

    }
}
```

Comment: If Thilo's answer was correct, you should upvote it (click the up-arrow above the vote counter) and then "accept" it (click the checkmark), to indicate that it was correct.

Comment: I was waiting for the timer to be done...not enough rep to up-vote it.

Comment: Ah, I see. If you create a second account (on superuser.com, for example) and link them you get 100 rep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int a = in.read(b,0,len);
if(a!=len){
```

That won't work. The InputStream may not read all the bytes you want, it may read only what is available right now, and return that much without blocking.

To [quote the Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) (emphasis mine):

> **Reads up to** len bytes of data from the input stream into an array of bytes. An attempt is made to read as many as len bytes, but **a smaller number may be read**, possibly zero. The number of bytes actually read is returned as an integer.

You need to continue reading in a loop until you have all the data you want (or the stream is finished).

Or, since you are using a DataInputStream, you can also use

```
in.readFully(b, 0, len);
```

which always reads exactly `len` bytes (blocking until those have arrived, throwing an exception when there is not enough data).

Comment: forgive my ignorance, but how can I do that while still keeping track of the length read? Thanks

Comment: For some reason I didn't see the readFully() in the API. It worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: This answer saved my life; I had 20 minutes before my final networking project was due and I had one bug I couldn't figure out. I desperation googled "java socket reads incorrect number of bytes". This was the first answer that came up, and it worked perfectly. Thank you!